# как в sql добавить нули перед числом

Tags: java, sql, kotlin

есть поля которое может принимать четырехзначные числа если он 25 добавить два нуля перед числом если 9 то три нуля а если 123 то 1 нол как сделать

Comment: Сервер БД нам предлагается угадать?

Comment: Если вы храните в БД числа, то никак. Ведущие нули смысоа не имеют при записи в БД. Форматируйте числа как вам надо при выводе их юзеру

Comment: либо хранить числа как тест и заносить их в базу уже в нужном виде

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin поможет написать такой код в одну строку.

```
val numInput = 25
val strInput = "$numInput".padStart(4, '0') //0025
```

https://pl.kotl.in/fDTuJC3A0